# Material UI Button - How can I use "::first-letter" pseudo element selector with MuiButton class?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to have sentence case with Button text inside Material UI Button.

https://mui.com/components/buttons/

text inside the button - `ADD FRIEND` should become to sentence case as `Add friend`.

I have tried to override the theme. But it does not target the element this way.
Please suggest if this is possible to do.

```
createTheme({
 components: {
  MuiButton: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        '&::first-letter': {
          textTransform: 'uppercase',
        },
      },
    }
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Please, see my answer. If it solved your issue, upvote it and make in the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They way I do it, is write the following code in makeStyles of the page/component:

```
  parentOfButton: {
    '& .MuiButton-root': {
      textTransform: 'none',
    },
  },
```

```
<Box className={classes.parentOfButton}>
  <Button>Text</Button>
</Box>
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried doing the same thing in createTheme, and it worked, here is the way I did it:

```
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textTransform: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Through styles, I could not make the first letter of the transmitted text capitalized until I wrapped the transmitted text in some kind of tag, for example

```
  .button {
    & > *::first-letter {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  }

  <Button className={s.button}>
    <p>some text</p>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button element may not have support for pseudo-elemements like `&::first-letter`.

What works for me is to instead wrap the text in Typography, which do have support for this css pseudo class.

```html
<Button>
    <Typography
        sx={{
            "&::first-letter": {
                textTransform: "capitalize",
            },
        }}
    >
    text
    </Typography>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

text-transform: 'inherit' should solve issue

```
MuiButton: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      textTransform: 'inherit',
      },
    },
},
```